# How can I get the URL for product's page using the Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

I checked out Shopify product API but result doesn't seem to return product page URL. The URL looks like resulted after some transformation on the title. Is there reliable well defined logic for this or any other method to get product page URL?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it as 'products/< product.handle >'. I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing it, but it works.

Comment: This is the correct method. `product.handle` is the URL-safe version of the product title used in the URL.

Comment: Cheers, saved me some messing around.

Comment: This work only and only if the store URL routing is: `products/< product.handle >`, otherwise it fails. some store have configure to use something like `collections/accessories/<product.handle>`

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn - You are right. Is there any way we get the url? Should not shopify return the product url in the api calls?

Comment: @HuckleberryFinn this is not correct - the canonical URL for a product is always `products/< product.handle >`, some themes however use the `within:` helper for a product URL, so that on the product page a breadcrumb can appear showing the collection where the user came from, however this is always optional. The user may have come from any collection, there is no primary collection associated with a product.

Answer (score 4):

I usually add this in `config/initializers/shopify_api.rb`:

```
module ShopifyAPI
  class Shop
    def store_url_for(entity)
      return "http://#{self.domain}/#{entity.class.element_name}/#{entity.handle}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete answer from Michael Johnston, you need to call ShopifyAPI::Shop.current before you can use store_url_for(entity).

For example, to get the url of a product in a controller:

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(@product_id)
shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
product_url = shop.store_url_for(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old post and maybe api has been upgraded because there is def. others url constructs such as collections/collection-name/products/product-name.

Still looking if there is a way to get unique product URI